# Плохо работает SGD в torch [load_boston dataset]

Tags: машинное-обучение, регрессия

Работаю с **load_boston** из sklearn. Модель линейная многомерная регрессия. Пытаюсь найти веса через SGD

```
# Loading data
df = load_boston()
DF = pd.DataFrame(df.data, columns=df.feature_names)  
target = df.target
```

Стандартизирую данные

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test)
X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train)
y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test)
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train)
```

Собственно, сам алгоритм с использованием оптимизатора из **torch**

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
# initial part for SGD
w = torch.randn([X_train.shape[1]], requires_grad=True)
 # forming of dataset with answers [Y]
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
# implementing random choice of elements from sample
generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
# building optimizer [implementing iteration process of SGD]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([w], lr=0.01)
# updating of learning rate
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, 
                                              lambda k: 1/np.sqrt(k+1))

list_of_loss_torch = []
for x, y in generator:
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    with torch.no_grad():
        list_of_loss_torch.append(
            torch.mean((X_train @ w.double() - y_train) ** 2))
        
    q = ((x @ w.double() - y) ** 2)
    q.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
```

Но проблема в том, что ошибка после выполнения всё равно очень большая ошибка (MSE = 588.4859469250911)

[image: Средняя ошибка по выборке]

```
plt.plot(list(range(len(list_of_loss_torch))), list_of_loss_torch)
```

Делал через **SGDRegressor** из sklearn, там ошибка была гораздо ниже, на тестовой выборке получилось всего
**MSE = 23.623407470385047**

** Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так? **
Совсем новичок, но уже который день не даёт покоя эта ситуация, хочется разобраться

Comment: попробуйте поиграть с гиперпараметрами - я бы для начала попробовал начать с меньшего learning_rate да и batch_size = 1 - это очень плохое значение для SGD - считать конечно будет быстро, но  и ошибка может быть больше. Попробуйте значения 16, 32, 64 в качестве batch_size...

Comment: @MaxU 
Большое спасибо за ответ!
А в качестве q в случае batch_size, отличного от 1, брать mean() или sum()?
Там ведь вектор получается